# Error " Property 'title' not found on object of type 'MyAnnotation' "

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm following this tutorial http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/how-to-access-mkmapkit-in-iphone/ to set annotations on a map in my IOS app , but I got 13 errors :

- " Property 'title' not found on object of type 'MyAnnotation' "  ( 4 times )
- " Property 'subtitle' not found on object of type 'MyAnnotation' " ( 4 times )
- " Property 'coordinate' not found on object of type 'MyAnnotation' " (4 times )
- " Property 'coordinate' not found on object of type 'id' " ( 1 time)

I get those mistakes one time for each annotation, and I've added 4 annotations ( that's why there are 4 times each mistake).
I really don't know what to do , I've tried many things but It didn't work . I'm a beginner in Objective-C so it is probably a really stupid mistake but I can't see it !

Pictures of the code:

- [viewDidLoad - part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uF1n.jpg)
- [viewDidLoad - part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yejd.jpg)
- [ViewController.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q5ZA.jpg)
- [MyAnnotation.m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op0Uo.jpg)
- [MyAnnotation.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzcQ4.jpg)

Comment: Did you #import "MyAnnotation.h" into ViewController.m?

Comment: Yes I've checked , I've imported it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your annotation objects should be objects that conform to the MKAnnotation protocol.  I'm guessing that your implementation of the protocol methods is not compliant.

Show what you have for those methods (which should be within your MyAnnotation object), if you don't see any obvious errors along this line of thought.